# How does 'as' work when used inside 'where'?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Learning gremlin and looking at examples I see the use of `as` inside of `where` steps to match against a previously labeled step.

For example, [from official recipes page](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence), a vertex is labeled 'v' with `as`, later on inside a coalesce it looks for an `inE` where the `outV` equals to 'v', but it does so using `as` again:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').as('v').
           V().has('software','name','ripple').
           coalesce(__.inE('created').where(outV().as('v')),
                    addE('created').from('v').property('weight',0.5))
```

If I were to just read the reference documentation this query would look to me like they are just labeling that `outV` step as 'v' and nothing more.

This functionality of `as` doesn't seem to be documented in the reference documentation, and only shows in the examples with no special mention of it.

Does the previous query achieve the same as the following?

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').as('v').
           V().has('software','name','ripple').
           coalesce(__.inE('created').where(outV().where(eq('v'))),
                    addE('created').from('v').property('weight',0.5))
```

Is this just a lack of documentation, or is there something I'm missing?

Is saying `as` has a special meaning inside 'where', correct? Or is there something else to take into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - `as()` has special meaning inside `where()`. It is described briefly as part of the `select()/where()` [usage](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#using-where-with-select) (see item 3) and in the `match()/where()` [usage](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.11/reference/#using-where-with-match). Basically when you write your query that way you are using `where()` with its variable binding form and is equivalent to the more direct form that you demonstrate in your second query. Personally, I tend to find the binding form a bit less readable, but that depends on the nature of the filter I guess and sometimes it represents the most clear way to structure the query.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, an `as` step is treated differently inside a `where` step to allow a step label created outside the where step to be treated as a label inside the `where` step and not a literal string.

There is a writeup here

http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#patternwhere